# Can I create wheel distributions of packages containing cython for other platforms?

Tags: python, cython, setuptools, python-wheel

When I create a wheel distribution with `python setup.py bdist_wheel` of a package which contains cython code, then the platform tag fits to my current platform. Projects like numpy / scipy have a lot of different wheels online and I guess they use CI / CD platforms like Travis / Azure Piplelines for that. However, I wondered: Can I create wheel distributions of packages containing cython for other platforms than my own, using only my computer?

### MVCE

fib.pyx

```
def fib_iterative_cython(int n):
        cdef long long a = 0
        cdef long long b = 1
        for i in range(n - 1):
            a, b = b, a + b
        return b
```

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("fib.pyx")
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: you can distribute sdist (source distribution). This forces the users to compile the sources so they have to install developer tools. `pip install` mostly handles compilation except `Cython`: you need to teach your users to install `Cython` first.

Detailed answer: no. Partially it's Python fault, but mostly not. There are problems at many levels. First, cross-compilers are problematic and cross-linkers even more so. Second, `setuptools` doesn't know any cross-compiler.

Solution: the only way to build C-modules is to build them natively in virtual machines or Docker containers.